# I can't get data from req.body in nodesjs + expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my code:

```
var express        =         require("express");
var bodyParser     =         require("body-parser");
var app            =         express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendfile("index.html");
});
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body)
  var user_name=req.body.user;
  var password=req.body.password;
  console.log("User name = "+user_name+", password is "+password);
  res.end("yes");
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Started on PORT 3000");
})
```

I set a console in post method function but it displayed:

```
{}
User name = undefined, password is undefined
```

I couldn't get any data from response. I had lookup doc but I couldn't find any error. I don't still understand. What mistake did i make?

Comment: Can you post your code for the login form?

Comment: @Mike I use postman to test api. I have not used form.

Comment: And you're sending the correct POST data ?

Comment: Please post the data you are sending with postman here.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I have solved by myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your data using Postman with the `content-type:application/json` in the header.  This will ensure that the server receives the data in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

I know what happens!

If I want to send data in `form-data`, here has good solution helps me:

[Result is undefined when I use form-data in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232086/result-is-undefined-when-i-use-form-data-in-postman)

If I use `x-www-form-urlencoded` to send data, it's actually valid!

I find when postman send json data without `content-type:application/json` in headers, it's definitely error. Now, I have added it. It can be valid.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your Snipet looks fine and should get data while you do `console.log(req.body)`
But the fact is please check the source of the client application you are using to post this data (Postman,Browser) etc.
If you use Postman please ensure that you do the following
1.If you send it as `JSON` format then send it as `content-type:application/json`

2.If you send the data via the form data then please make sure that you selected the `x-www-form-urlencoded`section